# Problem with PHP/Java bridge

Tags: php, mysql, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 6. I am running a php script using the JavaBridge. I get the following error when I run my code.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\xxxx\xxxxx.php on line 534
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what I've done but mine is working as I read the documentation. in my case it's MySQL and I am using Tomcat 7.

1. copy the correct VERSION of the PHP extension "php_mysql.dll" to the correspond "ext" directory, in my case it's in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\aeu\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\ext"
2. uncomment/add this line,

   extension = php_mysql.dll

in php.ini and mysql.ini file, in my case there're as C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\aeu\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\php.ini and C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\aeu\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\conf.d\mysql.ini

and lastly restart Tomcat. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things:

- Make sure that location of
  `php_mysql.dll` is included in the
  `PATH` env variable.
- Open your `php.ini` file, and look
  under the extensions. Make sure that
  the line for loading `php_mysql.dll`
  is not commented (make sure there
  isn't a `;` in front of it).

Comment: @unicornaddict: I did exactly as you said. I have installed WAMP. I added C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext to my PATH env variable. Also the php.ini is OK. I restarted tomcat. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to some missing `libmysql.dll`, try to look for this file (windows find could help) and make sure it sit's on a directory belonging to you PATH. (see this [topic](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,68276,111394#msg-111394))

Comment: Hum, try to put `libmysql.dll` in `c:\windows\system32` and see if that's help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure PHP with the option:   --with-mysql = path_to_mysql

I would just like to highlight Bruces question here relates to using the mysqli API (not the older mysql API)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working. HAD TO USE mysql**i**.ini INSTEAD OF mysql.ini in my case:
 
- Apache-Tomcat-9.0.10
 
- PHP Version 5.6.38
 
- JavaBridgeTemplate721.war
- MySql 8.0.12
...first had to copy `php5ts.dll` and `php-cgi.exe` to setup the PHP enabled Tomcat project to the:
`\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\`
and then copy `php_mysqli.dll` and setup the `mysqli.ini` to enable the mysqli.